# Supreme logo on a shirt

Tags: copyright

If I was to make a T-shirt/Hoodie with the supreme logo on it for personal use without reselling would that be considered illegal and if so what could I change to make it legal?

Comment: More of a question for the law stack exchange - but they likely have had dozens of those...

Answer (score 0):

Copyright laws vary quite much from country to country. Copyright law is also very very murky and highly non-intuitive. So this question becomes impossible to answer without knowing your exact locale.

Nobody is enforcing you making things though. Nor is anybody removing pirated merchandise of people, but dont go through customs. But no you can not morally do that.

However the question is: Why do you want a hoodie with a Supreme logo on it without supporting supreme? It kind of looses its point.

Also consider: If your making a hoodie that can literally be anything why would you copy something else? Make your own stuff stand out, that's much more valuable,

Comment: The reason was to make a practical joke because many of my friends like the brand so I would like to show them how easy it is to make one yourself.

Comment: And I’m not gonna claim that I bought it or that supreme is something i created

Comment: @AlbertFledelius Make one that says "inferior" that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding about all that is the same as P2P usage of the internet. If you're making it to produce profit, you'll be in trouble. If not (personal use), then you can make it. But then again, people will see it and most likely like it and ask that you make them one which will tempt you to start producing.

Comment: There snt actually anything that says P2P is OK in most places its just that enforcing it is too costly for the benefit. But again if you did the same thing with your own random text then you CAN do this and it may be a success or not.